# Change the appearance of AMCopen in separateanswersheet post-correct?

Tags: pdftex, exam, examdesign, auto-multiple-choice, mcexam

I am trying to make a template for post correction sheets, ( separateanswer sheet style) and i am running into some aesthetic issue.

Right now when i use AMCopen it appears as shown.

Presently [image: PresentView]

Its taking up too much space and doesn't look good.
How do i modify the options so that it looks like the other picture attached
[image: RequiredView]

I have attached an MWC.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[insidebox,noshuffle,postcorrect]{automultiplechoice}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\def\AMCbeginQuestion#1#2{\par\noindent{\bf Q #1} #2\hspace*{1em}}
\onecopy{1}{
\noindent

\noindent
\hrulefill
\begin{multicols}{3}\columnseprule=.4pt
    % \foreach \n in {0,...,22}{do something}
    \foreach \subject in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,5}{
        \begin{question}{\n}
            \begin{choicescustom}
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \end{choicescustom}
            \end{question}}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,5}{
            \begin{question}{\n}
            \AMCOpen{dots=true,width=1cm,framerule=0.5pt,lineheight=1cm}{\wrongchoice[w]{w}\scoring{0}\correctchoice[c]{c}\scoring{2}}
            \end{question}
    
    }}
\end{multicols}
}
\end{document}
```

P.S. I have created RequiredView in an entirely different document, there may be some spacing issues, or it might overall look different, but I only want to change how AMC open appears, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever comes looking for a solution, here is how i solved my issue.

I used the `lineup` option in AMCopen and it lined it up perfectly. Using it on my example above

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[insidebox,noshuffle,postcorrect]{automultiplechoice}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\def\AMCbeginQuestion#1#2{\par\noindent{\bf Q #1} #2\hspace*{1em}}
\onecopy{1}{
\noindent

\noindent
\hrulefill
\begin{multicols}{3}\columnseprule=.4pt
    % \foreach \n in {0,...,22}{do something}
    \foreach \subject in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,5}{
        \begin{question}{\n}
            \begin{choicescustom}
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \wrongchoice{}%
            \end{choicescustom}
            \end{question}}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,5}{
            \begin{question}{\n}
%%%%%%%%%%changed the below line only - start
            \AMCOpen{dots=true,lineup=true}{\wrongchoice[w]{w}\scoring{0}\correctchoice[c]{c}\scoring{2}}
%%%%%%%%%%changed the above line only - end
            \end{question}
    
    }}
\end{multicols}
}
\end{document}
```

Now the output looks like

[image]

Which is exactly how i needed it for single word/integer/numerical answers